# Form on the left, maps on the right

Tags: css, forms

This is the current situation (messed up): http://bit.ly/NK8s12

And this is the result yet to achieve (pic): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lb8U.png

The CSS is at: http://bit.ly/QoQO52

Comment: *...here I am, stuck in the middle with you!* That's going to be in my head all night, now. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
.info {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Selected your answer.